# How to post a file via AJAX using pure Javascript in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to post a file via AJAX using pure Javascript. I cannot use any libraries and I only can use IE 11.

I am getting a

> "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference" error at line 4.

```js
function getQuotation() {
  var data = {};
  data.manualTriggerDTO = {};
  data.manualTriggerDTO.orgShortName = document.getElementById('manualTriggerDTO.orgShortName').value;
  data.filename0 = document.getElementById('filename0').files[0];

  function handler() {
    if (oReq.readyState == 4 /* complete */ ) {
      if (oReq.status == 200) {
        console.log(oReq.responseText);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(data);
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (oReq != null) {
    oReq.open("POST", 'upload.do?functionName=uploadJobs', true);
    oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    oReq.send(data);
    oReq.onreadystatechange = handler;
  } else {
    window.console.log("AJAX (XMLHTTP) not supported.");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="manualTriggerDTO.orgShortName" />
<input type="file" id="filename0" onchange="getQuotation()" />
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(document.getElementById('filename0'))`?

Comment: It is an object and the value is C:\Users\myname\Documents\Book1_working_DevDB.xls"

Comment: I do not get the error in my IE11 with the above snippet. I get `filename0": {
    "lastModifiedDate": "2019-06-11T09:00:18.000Z",
    "name": "bla.png",
    "size": 281495,
    "type": "image/png",`

Comment: Unfortunately, my IE document mode emulation is 5. Any way to get around it?